# HTML events changing input text, not incrementally

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have an `input` field with `type="number"`. After this value is changed the page will perform validation and if failed it will show a bunch of information to the visitor.

So this validation should only be done when:

- Pasting something into the box
- Typing in the box and then pressing tab to select another input
- Typing in the box and then clicking outside the box
- Pressing enter (which performs a click on the submit button)
- Clicking increment and decrement buttons

And not when:

- Typing a single digit (as the input is not complete)

Are there HTML events available for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually try the event `.onchange` / `addEventListener('change',{})` or in your case, since you are asking for an html-inline-solution: `input onchange="yourFunc()"`? It sounds like that's pretty much what you want.

(`.onchange` won't trigger as long as you are just typing).

Here's a very simple demo to stress the behaviour of `.onchange`:

as you will see, it fulfills most of your needs:

```
Typing in the box and then pressing tab to select another input
Typing in the box and then clicking outside the box
Pressing enter (which performs a click on the submit button)
Clicking increment and decrement buttons
```

The only thing missing is triggering the event upon pasting smth in it, but the user can just press enter, click elsewhere, tab etc. to fire your function.

```js
function fire(){
  console.log("changed");
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onchange="fire()">
<button>a non-functional button to focus on</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is the `onblur` or `focusout` event. It fires when the element will be out of focus. Basically, the opposite of `onfocus`.

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="myFunction()">
```

You may want to use it in combination with other events (`onclick`) which you require for the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input")

    input.onchange = function () {
        alert("changed")
    }
```

```html
 <input type="number">
```